# SQL Function error [invalid use of side-effecting operator 'select' within a function]

Tags: sql-server

Can any one help me to create function in sql server 2012 ,I M new in sql it shows error [invalid use of side-effecting operator 'select' within a function]

```
CREATE FUNCTION Get_RearEnd_Outflow( @I_TXN_ID INT)
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @V_COUNT INT
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @V_COUNT FROM IRR_CHARGES_M
  RETURN @V_COUNT
END
```

Comment: `RearEnd_Outflow`... Not a function I'd want to use :-)

Answer (score 6):

The [correct syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx) should be

```
CREATE FUNCTION Get_RearEnd_Outflow( @I_TXN_ID INT)
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @V_COUNT INT
  SELECT @V_COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IRR_CHARGES_M)
  RETURN @V_COUNT
END
```

however [SET is the better way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx) to assign variable in T-SQL

```
  SET @V_COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IRR_CHARGES_M)
```

**EDIT 2:** For multiple assignment you can use `SELECT`

For multiple assin

```
SELECT  @variableOne = someColumn,  @variableTwo = someColumn from tblTable
```

**EDIT:** From the MSDN link about slect

> For assigning variables, we recommend that you use SET @local_variable instead of SELECT @local_variable. For more information, see SET @local_variable.

Comment: +1 for correct answer. But why `set` is the better way? the only difference I can think of is that `set` will raise an error when you assigning variable to `select` which returns more than one row, and `select` will assign variable to first row.

Comment: I added the quote from MSDN pages, also SET is ANSI  to set variable while SELECT is not. You could also look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866767/set-vs-select-whats-the-difference

Comment: DEAR WHAT WILL I DO WHEN SQL select QUERY HAVE TO MANY COLUMNS IN ABOVE cREATE FUNCTION STATEMENT

Comment: @user1831355 for multiple column you have to use SELECT. Does EDIT2  answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
    CREATE FUNCTION Get_RearEnd_Outflow()
     RETURNS int
     AS
     BEGIN
     DECLARE @COUNT INT;
    SET @COUNT =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IRR_CHARGES_M);
return @COUNT
    END
     GO
```

or use :

```
CREATE FUNCTION Get_RearEnd_Outflow()
     RETURNS int
     AS
     BEGIN
    return  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IRR_CHARGES_M)

    END
     GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Get_RearEnd_Outflow( @I_TXN_ID INT)
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @V_COUNT INT;
    SET @V_COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IRR_CHARGES_M);
  RETURN @V_COUNT;
END
```

Comment: DEAR WHAT WILL I DO WHEN  SQL select QUERY HAVE TO MANY COLUMNS IN ABOVE cREATE FUNCTION STATEMENT

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but you could replace `SELECT COUNT(*)` with `SELECT (<columnanme>)` and replace `<columnname>` with whichever column contains the values you want counted.