# How can I set a BIT variable based on a value variable?

Tags: sql-server

I have:

```
DECLARE @Authenticated BIT

If @@ROWCOUNT > 0
 begin
   SELECT @Authenticated = 1
 end ELSE
 begin
   SELECT @Authenticated = 0
 end
```

Is there a way I could do this without the BEGIN END and also is setting a BIT datatype a good way to represent True of False?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `CASE` to do this more concisely, like so:

```
 SET @Authenticated = (SELECT CASE WHEN @@ROWCOUNT >0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Also, `BIT` would be a good choice to represent True/False, since that is pretty much what bits work like - either 0 or 1.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept this answer in 4 minutes. Can I also ask. Is using SET a better way to set a value. My code is using: SELECT @Result = 'F'.  Should I be using SET for this instead?

Comment: This answer gives a good comparison between the 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866767/set-vs-select-whats-the-difference

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `IF .. ELSE` construct a bit like below and use `SET` command

```
DECLARE @Authenticated BIT

If @@ROWCOUNT > 0
SET @Authenticated = 1
ELSE
SET @Authenticated = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Authenticated BIT
SET @Authenticated = @@ROWCOUNT
```

should also work since BIT values are true/1 if not zero.