# Understanding SQL syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm a C# developer trying to become more familiar with SQL Server stored procedures.

I'm a little confused as to why the syntax in "A" works and "B" does not work with `Set @id`. What is happening here that makes "B" require `Select` instead of `Set`?

Example A (works)

```
DECLARE @currDateTime DateTime

SET @currDateTime = GetDate()

SELECT @currDateTime
```

Example B (does not work)

```
 DECLARE @id int

 SET @id = ID FROM [MyTable] WHERE [Field1] = 'Test'
```

Example C (works)

```
 DECLARE @id int

 SELECT @id = ID 
 FROM [MyTable] 
 WHERE [Field1] = 'Test'
```

Comment: `FROM` is belong to `SELECT` not to `SET`. For more information look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866767/set-vs-select-whats-the-difference)

Comment: When You retrieve value from table use 'Select' . In case of simple assignment statement You can use 'Set'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT` is a built-in type of SQL clause that runs a query and returns a result-set in the format of a table *or* it assigns variables to the results from a query.

`SET` is a clause that sets a variable.

The two are very different.  `SELECT` has various other associated clauses, such as `FROM`, `WHERE` and so on; `SET` does not.  `SELECT` returns values as a result table in its normal usage; `SET` does not.

Admittedly, both look the same in an expression such as:

```
set @currDateTime = GetDate();
select @currDateTime = GetDate();
```

However, it is really a coincidence that the syntax for setting a single value happens to look the same.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because it's incorrect SQL syntax, You need `SELECT` when fetching data from table/view/table function.

You could use SET when using an expression though i.e:

```
DECLARE @Id bigint


SET @Id = (SELECT TOP 1 Id
                FROM MyTable
                WHERE Field1 = 'Test')
```